# Using PARFOR on a finite difference scheme

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, pde, parfor

I am trying to solve a nonlinear diffusion equation using a finite difference approach. It is essentially two nested `for` loops, the inner one is loops over the grid, the outer one advances the equation in time, somewhat like this:

```
for i=1:(Nt-1)
    for j=2:(Nx-1)

        %%% simple diffusion equation
        c(2,i+1) = c(1,i) + D*dt/dx/dx*(cL(1,j-1)2*cL(1,j)+cL(1,j+1));

    end

    %re-impose BCs
    c(2,1)=1; 
    c(2,Nx)=1; 

    %save into solution matrix
    if mod(i,floor(Nt/sol_no))==0
        sol_c(sol_i+1,:) = c(2,:);
        t_axis(sol_i+1,1) = i*dt;
        sol_i=sol_i+1;
    end

    %flip rows 1 and 2
    c = flipud(c);

end
```

To save memory, c is only a 2-by-Nx matrix which I keep flipping on every time increment, saving, say, every 100-th instance into a solution matrix.

Note that I used the simple diffusion equation here for the sake of clarity. The problem is that in reality I have to use a very fine grid (about 200,000 points ideally) in order to account for some rapidly changing coefficients which are a function of space. This, coupled with the stability criterion imposes a severe restriction on the size of the time step and the total time.

Now, I'd like to optimise my code and I figured one way to go about it is to use the `parfor` instead of `for` in the inner loop. Every element in the c(2,:) row is only dependent on the elements from row c(1,:) so this should work, right? But when I try to run it it runs forever and doesn't produce anything. I didn't show it in the snippet but all the variables are already initialised when the loop starts so I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I read through the `parfor` documentation but I didn't find anything useful. I suspect it must have something to do with slicing but I'm not sure how to tackle it. Also, maybe I'm missing some other more efficient approach to the problem so any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm adding the gist of my code stripped down to bare bones. `parfor` performs much slower than `for`.

```
tic
gridpoints = 400000;
time_iter = 200;

c1 = ones(1,gridpoints);
c2 = ones(1,gridpoints);
x = linspace(0,1,gridpoints);
k = 1.0000001;


for j=1:time_iter

    parfor i=2:gridpoints-1
       c2(i) = c1(i-1) + k*c1(i) - c1(i+1);
    end

c1=c2;
end

toc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the inner loop entirely, and use Matlab's vectorization (using your second example), which is much faster :

```
c2(2:end-1) = c1(1:end-2) + k * c1(2:end-1) - c1(3:end);
```

That being said, you can even eliminate c2 entirely:

```
c(2:end-1) = c(1:end-2) + k * c(2:end-1) - c(3:end);
```

And might want to add the boundary conditions while we're at it:

```
c = [1; c(1:end-2) + k * c(2:end-1) - c(3:end); 1];
```

You can also create a vector outside the outer loop (idx = [2:gridpoints-1];) and replace the indices appropriately to clarify the code.

Also, if you're running into stability issues, and implicit scheme might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, this speeds it up quite significantly (3 -4 times) but resource monitor shows that three out of eight cores are still idle so I assume it could be optimised further in some way.

About an implicit scheme: the equation is not that simple and must be evaluated on a fine grid. Solving it implicitly is also complicated and I simply don't have the mathematics needed for that.

Comment: Matlab may not be able to use all 8 cores, depending on which version you're using. Apart from that, coding it in C (mex file) might yield better performance, but that's not always the case; vectorization is pretty efficient.